# Where can I upload my pictures?

Tags: photo-sharing, photos

I need to upload more than 800MB of pictures onto a photo sharing service such as Google Picasa, but I don't have space for it.

I was considering to use Flickr (can I upload 800MB at once ?) although I don't like the idea of splitting my pictures over multiple services.

Of course I don't want to pay.

Comment: Free storage of Picasa is 1024MB and you can upload them at once using the standalone Picasa app.

Comment: Flickr will give you 1TB of space plus the storage limits throughout the Google Apps (Drive, Google+, Picasa have been haromized, having a minimum of 25GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Flickr user but from [what I've read](http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/#65), Flickr offers 300 MB of free storage each calendar month with storage counter reset every month, so it's *not an option*.
If you want to stick with Picasa without paying the fee for 20GB storage, you need to resize your pictures to a resolution lower than 800x800 as pictures that size *no longer count* towards your storage limit, more infos [here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/news/picasa-unlimited-free-storage/).

Comment: @Kraymer - Flickr offers 300MB of [free storage per month](http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/#65) for free accounts.

Comment: @Barry It doesn't offer the best UI though.. Picasa WebAlbums is offering much better user experience with the minimalistic UI.

Comment: and $5/year is not too much for 20GB of storage and for the backup of your valuable photos :)

Comment: @Lipis: Well that depends on whether you like the minimalistic UI ;-) I must admit though, I do find Flickr to be a bit "all over the place"

Comment: @Barry Thx, it's corrected now!

Comment: @Barry by minimalistic I mean straight to the point.. album/photos/view/full screen end of story.. not the chaos of Flickr :)

Comment: Flickr now offers a full terabyte of free storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [sugarsync.com](http://www.sugarsync.com). It is not exactly a photo sharing service, but it has some specific functionalities for photo/album sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our site, http://www.morguefile.com, We allow for unlimited uploads but its not private (anyone can see your photos). There is a free stock photo section or a portfolio section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned it, but there is **25GB of free storage** with **[Windows Live Skydrive](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-skydrive)**.  All you need is a Windows Live ID (i.e. a Hotmail account).

> Store, access, and share thousands of documents, photos, and Microsoft Office files on Windows Live SkyDrive. SkyDrive password-protects your files so you control who has access to them.